# How can I convert an html tag with another html tag in angularjs.

Tags: angularjs

For eg.

```
<h3>www.domain.com</h3>
```

should be converted to

```
<a>www.domain.com</a>
```

under certain logic

Comment: Please include some code you have tried :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the angular way you can use ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if. e.g.

in controller (Just an example, change this so your logic sets true/false to show/hide):

```
$scope.showLink = true;
```

in view:

```
<h3 ng-if="!showLink">www.domain.com</h3>
<a ng-if="showLink">www.domain.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6LeD3ClFuqQzlSltgvzK?p=preview) which could come in handy if you were to have to toggle between more than just two elements.

**js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.expression = "link";
});
```

**html**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-switch="expression">
      <h3 ng-switch-when="text">www.domain.com</h3>
      <a ng-switch-when="link">www.domain.com</a>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="expression = (expression === 'text' ? 'link' : 'text')">Toggle</button>
  </body>
```